# my validation and training loss keep increasing, have i over simplified my network?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, model, tensorflow2.0

I am training a 3 layer conv autoencoder and reconstruction using 3 layer conv decoder.

issue is my both training loss and validation loss keep increasing.

Is the network not able to learn more generic feature as it is small ?
or there could be more reason

[6k images with constant learning rate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZliXP.png) (saffron color validation, blue color training)

since the first learning curve shown at some point the model error shoot, i have tried a dynamic learning rate deceasing over epochs,and with more images 10k
[10k image with learning rate decreasing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIV4P.png)

So my question is, am i simplifying my network ? should I add more layers/neuron to my network ?

Answer (score -1):

After increasing a layer also the number of neuron per layer, i think i have better learning rate,

sharing the result.
[with more number of layers and neurons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33LuP.png)

Conclusion: My hypothesis was right, My network was over simplified, having a deeper layer curve.